# Get Second to last character position from string using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring, indexof

I have a dynamically formed string like - `part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc`

In this string I want to get the substring based on second to last occurrence of `"."` so that I can get and `part3.abc`

Is there any direct method available to get this?

Comment: Are the lengths of each part dynamic? Or are they known?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use:

```
'part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc'.split('.').splice(-2).join('.'); // 'part3.abc'
```

You don't need jQuery for this.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing to do with jQuery. You can use a regular expression:

```
var re = /[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$/;
var match = s.match(re);
if (match) {
  alert(match[0]);
}
```

or

```
'part1.abc.part2.abc.part3.abc'.match(/[^.]+\.[^.]+$/)[0];
```

but the first is more robust.

You could also use split and get the last two elements from the resulting array (if they exist).